# Fastest way from 10 to 1 with everyone in between

Tags: word, wordplay, letters, word-ladder

I got inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84918/fastest-way-from-8-to-7) from trolley813 to make this puzzle.

How fast one can get from TEN to ONE, passing each number in between?

The rules are simple:

> - You are only allowed to change one letter at a time.
> - At each step of the way, you must have a legitimate English word. Thus, something like going from "EIGHT" to "EIGHN" is not a valid step, but from "FIGHT" to "NIGHT" would be.
> - Here is an example going from TEN to NINE: TEN - TENT - LENT - LINT - LINE - NINE

Good luck!

Comment: Do you require the intermediate numbers to be passed _in order_ or not?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention

Comment: When going from SIX to FIVE should the extra letter be added first, or last? And when going from THREE to TWO should the letters be removed first or last? Must they be the *end* two letters?

Comment: That's up to you :)

Comment: That would have been my next puzzle to be posted today..just the reverse...I even got the title ready....it would have been..wow!!,,zero to sixty in 3 seconds..zero to ten not so fast...with some rule changes.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry if I messed up your plan :(

Comment: I did ZERO - HERO - HERE - [HENE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium–neon_laser) - HONE - ONE, if anyone cares...:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way. It probably isn't close to optimal. **42 steps** if I've counted right.

> TEN tin tine NINE sine sinh sigh sight EIGHT sight sigh sign sin sen seen SEVEN
>  seen see sex SIX sin sine fine FIVE fire fir for FOUR for foe toe the thee THREE
>  tree tee toe to TWO to ton tone ONE

Credit where due: the path from EIGHT to SEVEN is derived from [Hunter's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/84919/19114) to an earlier puzzle, though not much of that answer remains in what I have there now. JonMark Perry spotted what in hindsight should have been an obvious improvement in the path from FOUR to THREE.

Definitions of the least familiar words above:

> **sinh**: hyperbolic sine; a Thai garment
>  **sen**: since; a Japanese coin
>  **thew**: strength

Comment: you could go THE - THEE - THREE

Comment: oh yes, so I could; how extremely stupid not to have thought of that.

Comment: Because this puzzle is secretly nine puzzles wearing a trench coat, we can compare the number of steps taken to the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two words; this should give a very useful estimate for choosing which intervals are likely to be the easiest ones to improve.  As I'm writing this comment, the theoretically perfect intervals are TEN-NINE and SEVEN-SIX, and all the rest are one off the theoretical optimum, except EIGHT-SEVEN, which is is off by two.

Comment: well done, that's awesome!

Comment: Is TWO - OWE - ONE valid or is the TWO - OWE technically more than one switch?

Comment: TWO->OWE is nothing like valid. Why would it be?

Answer (score 12):

### Best solution so far: **38** steps

9-7 from @Gareth, and sien from @devyndraen thanks!

> TEN tin tine NINE sine sinh sigh sight EIGHT sight sigh sign sien seen SEVEN seen see sex SIX fix fie FIVE fie fir for FOUR for fore tore thre THREE thee the tho TWO to ton on ONE

Comment: Couldn't find "thre" in any dictionary, tho.

Comment: @Bass all words are supported by wiktionary, such as this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thre

Comment: But it is obsolete...

Comment: @justhalf but they are english words... :)

Comment: So far as I can tell SIEN is an obsolete spelling of SEEN and SCION and THRE an obsolete spelling of THREE. In my book, those aren't words, although they were words once.

Answer (score 12):

This is a proof that Omega Krypton's answer of 38 is optimal, as long as these words are nonexistent (single implication):

> EEVEN,EINE,ENINE,FIUR,FIVR,FOVE,NIGE,NINH,OWO,,SEGEN,SEVET,SEVHN,SIVEN,TNO,TWE

First, a calculation of the theoretical best (although no suitable words may exist), by using a Levenshteins distance (word difference by letters) [calculator](https://planetcalc.com/1721/):

> TEN -> NINE = 3, Gareth's, Omega's, devyndraen's answers already
>   optimized
>
> NINE -> EIGHT = 4, Currently answers have 5 steps
>
> EIGHT -> SEVEN = 5,  Currently answers have 6+ steps
>
> SEVEN -> SIX = 4,  Gareth's, Omega's, devyndraen's answers already
>   optimized
>
> SIX -> FIVE = 3, Omega's, devyndraen's answers already optimized
>
> FIVE -> FOUR = 3,  Currently answers have 4 steps
>
> FOUR -> THREE = 5, Omega's answer optimized (there is some dispute
>   there?)
>
> THREE -> TWO = 4, Omega's, devyndraen's answers already optimized
>
> TWO -> ONE = 3,  Currently answers have 4 steps
>
> Theoretical minimum = 3+4+5+4+3+3+5+4+3 = 34

Now let's analyse the algorithm and already existing answers on each non-optimized point to see if there is room for improvement:

NINE -> EIGHT = 4
This keeps the I intact, substitutes N,N,E, and adds T. One of the following words would have to exist:
ENINE,EINE,NIGE,NINH.

EIGHT -> SEVEN = 5
This obviously is 5 substitutions. One of these would be needed(reverse from seven): EEVEN,SIVEN,SEGEN,SEVHN,SEVET

FIVE -> FOUR = 3
3 substitutions, would need: FOVE,FIUR,FIVR

TWO -> ONE = 3
3 substitutions, would need: OWO,TNO,TWE

Q.E.D.

Comment: It's pretty easy to demonstrate that TWO to ONE isn't possible in 3 steps. To do that, your first step would need to change either the first, second or third letter of the source word (TWO) into the corresponding letter of the target word (ONE). That would give you OWO, TNO, or TWE, none of which are valid English words.

Comment: @Anothony I didn't expect so many upvotes, so I took it a little further in much the way you describe :)

Comment: What about https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segen? ;-)

Comment: EINE and SEGEN are German words, if that helps ...

Answer (score 6):

39 steps (40 words):

> TEN tin tine NINE sine sinh sigh sight EIGHT sight sigh sign sien seen SEVEN seen see sex SIX fix fie FIVE fire fore for FOUR for foe toe the thee THREE thee the tho TWO to ton tone ONE

Word 6 courtesy of @Gareth

Definition of less-known words:

> sinh - hyperbolic sine; a Thai garment
>  sien - a scion; descendant (from Collin's English Dictionary)
>  tho - nonstandard spelling of though